# Resolve host name of wss protocol with socket?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

How can resolve a host name with wss protocol by socket?
I tried this but failed:

`import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ip = socket.gethostbyname('wss://domain.tld')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wss://domain.tld` is not a hostname, it's a URL. You can't resolve a URL with a socket, you have to parse it as a URL to get the hostname out of it, and then you can resolve that. It doesn't matter whether the scheme is wss, http, or rsync; any scheme that has a `netloc` field will work the same way.

For example, using [`urllib.parse`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse # in 2.x it's from urlparse
>>> url = 'wss://domain.tld'
>>> bits = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
>>> netloc = bits.netloc
>>> netloc
'domain.tld'
```

So we're done, right?

Nope. A `netloc` can be either a host, or a host:port. And you can't just `split(':')`, because IPv6 addresses can have colons in them—but only if they're enclosed in brackets. So, to get the `host` part of a `netloc`, you need to do something like this:

```
>>> host, _, port = netloc.rpartition(':')
>>> if ']' in port: host = netloc
>>> host
'domain.tld'
```

And now we *are* done, we've got a hostname or IP address, which we can pass to [`socket.gethostbyname`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).

But a couple notes on that.

First, you don't need to create a `socket.socket` object to call `gethostbyname`; it's a top-level function on the module, that doesn't need any socket objects.

Second, `gethostbyname` doesn't work on IPv6, and has some limitations even on IPv4, so you may want to use [`getaddrinfo`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) instead.

So, finishing up:

```
>>> import socket
>>> addresses = socket.getaddrinfo(host, None) # or host, port if you prefer
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Well, that's to be expected, since our hostname is `domain.tld`, and there's no such domain. But if we used, say, `www.google.com`, we'd get back a nice list of a couple dozen IPv4 addresses and, if your system has IPv6 connectivity, a couple of IPv6 ones as well. You can just use the first one, or prefer IPv4 to IPv6 or vice-versa, or discriminate on some other field. (You can also filter on various fields in the first place by passing more arguments to `getaddrinfo`.)

Comment: I know a bit about socket programming :) and thanks for reminding me I  dont need to create socket object. just copied that... I written a proxy server and now it cannot handle the web socket.anyway thanks

Comment: @SoroushKhosravi: Yes, if you want to talk to a wss server, you'll need to create or install a WebSocket client library or a WebSocket proxy. That's a whole separate problem. And SO isn't a good place to get help picking a library or proxy (but start at Wikipedia, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations), and of course [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=websocket&submit=search) if you want to go the library route).